# Stage size aspect ratio

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, printing, aspect-ratio, stage

I'm creating a small project in adobe air 2 and wondering for stage ratio.

I want to set the size of stage is 2490x3510 pixels (300dpi A4)

However the issue that I have now is the monitor size do not support for my stage size. I mean my monitor size more smaller than stage one such as 1920x1200 or 1400x800.

If then I cannot get the real size document when I print my stage.

It is a more sophisticated than I think.
So I'd like to know, is it possible for me to set the stage size at 851x1200 pixels with 2.925 scale ratio value?

Whatever I load any image or movieclip, I have to resize the size with 2.925 ratio. Is this a good way or not?

Or could you give a some trick for resolving my agony?

Comment: That's fine, you can downscale your app to fit your screen size. Use some container for all content and set `scaleX/scaleY` for it

Comment: Is this an AIR or Web application?  You can leave your stage at a native size of 2490x3510 and tell the container to scale it to the screen size.  Though performance wise it might be better to just make whatever you're printing that size and scale it on the display.  A better question might be to show your printing code and ask how to make it print at the resolution you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<canvas id="mygame"></canvas>
```

CSS

```
#mygame {
   transform:scale(0.5);
}
```

This way you can have high-resolution images for printing in a scaled-down container.